# Plone ERROR ZServer uncaptured python exception

Tags: apache-2.2, sles, plone, zope

Afternoon,
I'm running Plone 2.5.3 on SLES 10.  With a separate Apache server (192.168.6.80) using mod rewrite to access Plone.

Recently been experiencing slow performance loading pages.  When I checked the ZOPE events.log there are lots of:

```
2011-02-09T13:20:18 ERROR ZServer uncaptured python exception, closing channel <ZServer.HTTPServer.zhttp_channel connected 192.168.6.80:42815 at 0x2aaaacaf97a0 channel#: 349 requests:> (socket.error:(104, 'Connection reset by peer') [/opt/Plone-2.5.3/Python-2.4.4/lib/python2.4/asynchat.py|initiate_send|219] [/opt/Plone-2.5.3/lib/python/ZServer/medusa/http_server.py|send|417] [/opt/Plone-2.5.3/Python-2.4.4/lib/python2.4/asyncore.py|send|332])
```

I found a post which suggested this error is just caused by users navigaing away from a page before the request is complete, can anyone confirm this is normal Zope behaviour?  Maybe I just need to reduce the log level?

Cheers,

Nathan.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed normal behaviour, the errors are indeed caused by prematurely closing the socket (before the request has been fully read or the response has been fully sent).